# VWP or B-2 Visa required?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

My husband and I are planning a 6 months road trip in USA and Canada. We both hold passports that allow for VWP for 90 days.

1. If we entered on VWP, I have read that we cannot extend beyond the 90 days granted by VWP and must leave by the 90 days. Is this true?
2. Should we apply for a B2 visa before we leave?

Comment: It seems as if you might already be aware of this, but just in case, since you say you are traveling through the US and Canada. Going into Canada does not stop the 90-day VWP counter. OTOH, you _could_ spend 90 days in the US, and 90 in Canada, if that were allowed. Of course :) this begs the question if there is 90-days worth of sights to see in Canada? :)

Comment: The answers to your questions are Yes and Yes.  What other response were you hoping to hear?  That the 90-day limit on VWP entries isn't in fact limited to 90 days?

Answer (score 9):

You cannot extend your stay if you entered the United States under the Visa Waiver Program. The [only exceptions](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1024/~/how-to-extend-my-visa-waiver-program-stay-in-the-u.s.-if-there-is-an-emergency) to this deal with medical emergencies, flights canceled due to weather, and the like.

If you enter on a B2 visa, you can stay for [up to one year](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/64101/3221). You *can* [apply to extend your visit](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/USCIS/Resources/C1en.pdf) further by filing form I-539 online ([more info](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/m-752.pdf)).